# Web3JS + React: Fetching API data to use in a call

Tags: web3js, react, external-api

I have the following solidity function:

```
contract testCall {
    string private globalKey;

    function setKey(string key) public {
        globalKey = key;
    }
}
```

As this function is called from the React client, I need to construct a promise that would fetch the key from an external API `https://KEYAPILINK`, which returns only one string, so that:

1. the user clicks on a button,
2. the key is being fetched from the API
3. the fetched key is then inserted into the Web3JS call as the `setKey(fetched_key)`

Can't put together the code of this promise. What would be the best way?